# Novice Python question: How to create crosstabs across multiple predictor variables and outcome variable

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

Using the following test data frame containing binary 0/1 variables:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0]], columns=["y", "age_catg", "race_catg", "sex_catg"])
```

I'd like to use the `pd.crosstab()` function to create two-way tables of y vs. age_catg, race_catg, sex_catg in order to check for complete separation of y values among the predictor categories.

My actual data frame contains several thousand predictors, so rather than explicitly naming the age, race, and sex predictors I'd prefer to use columns #'s. However, I'm still confused with row & column references in Python - for example the following code doesn't work:

```
desc_tab = pd.crosstab(test_df[:,1],  test_df[:,2:4])     
desc_tab
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use integer indexes you need the [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) method:

```
pd.crosstab(test_df.iloc[:, 1], test_df.iloc[:, 2])
```

Output:

```
race_catg  0  1
age_catg       
0          3  3
```

You can pass several arrays/series to either columns or rows if you put them in a list:

```
pd.crosstab(test_df.iloc[:, 1], [test_df.iloc[:, 2], test_df.iloc[:, 3]])

race_catg  0     1
sex_catg   0  1  0  1
age_catg             
0          1  2  2  1
```

### EDIT

If you want to batch define the columns by their indices (**list** is a reserved word in python, please don't use it):

```
cols = [test_df.iloc[:, i] for i in [2, 3]]
pd.crosstab(test_df.iloc[:, 1], cols)
```

Output:

```
race_catg  0     1   
sex_catg   0  1  0  1
age_catg             
0          1  2  2  1
```

Comment: Thank you - so to pass a list of data frame columns into `pd.crosstab` I'd do something like: `list = [test_df.iloc[:,1:4]]; pd.crosstab(test_df.iloc[:, 0], list)`? (Although this doesn't work.)

Comment: Try `cols = [test_df.iloc[:, i] for i in range(1, 4)]; pd.crosstab(test_df.iloc[:, 0], cols)`. I edited my answer.